# Why is there a run-time error when freeing memory?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct a {
    int n;
    char *p;
} a;

int main()
{
    a A;
    A.p = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    A.n = 100;
    strcpy(A.p, "just testing");
    //A.p = "just testing" <-- runtime error

    printf("%d\n%s\n", A.n, A.p);

    free(A.p);

    return 0;
}
```

If you use strcpy, it will run without any problems.

However, giving a string like  `A.p = "just testing` causes a runtime error.

Why would I get an error if I put the string directly?

What is the difference between using strcpy and putting it directly?

Comment: The error is probably at `free(A.p);`. It no longer points to the mem you `malloc`d so you are trying to `free` the wrong memory.

Comment: You should read the chapter dealing with strings and the `str...` functions (`strcpy`, `strcat`, `strlen` etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A.p = "just testing"` makes pointer `p` to points to a string literal `"just testing"`. The memory you allocated is now lost and your program has memory leak. Now You are trying to free a memory which is not allocated by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`.
The behaviour of `free` is undefined if the memory is not allocated, to pointer `p`, by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @machine_1 that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strcpy` *copies* the contents of the string literal `"just testing"` into the memory location pointed to by `A.p` (which was returned by `malloc`).

In contrast, the assignment assigns the address of the string literal `"just testing"` to `A.p` which *overwrites*  the memory address returned from `malloc`.  When you later call `free`, you're passing it the address of the string literal instead of malloc'ed memory.  Passing an address to `free` that wasn't returned from `malloc` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

the variable "p" inside your struct "a" is a pointer so "p" only can be assigned a reference to the space in memory where the variable is. Here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm is a place where your can get some info about pointers. But related to your question you have to assign a reference not a string value. For example, declaring char r = "hi" and the the assignment statement could be A.p = &r; Regards!